# mysql on ec2 amazon instance attempting to login with incorrect user

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I've set up a very basic LAMP setup on an ec2 server, all good it seems to work.

However i've seen for some queries a failure to connect to the mysql server with the following error:

```
[07-Jul-2013 20:15:41 Australia/Sydney] PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'ec2-user'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /var/www/html/mycobber/class/sql/SqlQuery.class.php on line 40
[07-Jul-2013 20:15:41 Australia/Sydney] PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /var/www/html/xxx/xxxx/sql/SqlQuery.class.php on line 40
```

the thing i dont' understand is the fact that in no location in my mysql connection configuration does it specify the user ec2-user. this is the default user when I log onto the unix server. I've set up a separate account to actually run all my processes, i dont' even use the es2-user.

I've looked online and can't see anything to explain this. does anyone have an idea what's going on here. it's not all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can't call `mysql_real_escape_string` without having opened a connection with `mysql_connect` first.

Quoting from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

> A MySQL connection is required before using **mysql_real_escape_string()** otherwise an error of level **`E_WARNING`** is generated, and **`FALSE`** is returned.

The error message refers to your default username @ localhost because you haven't opened a connection with specific credentials yet - it doesn't know what account details to use.

Comment: ok that clears up why it's using ec2-user, I've found that in the doccos thanks. Not sure why it works locally however. Thanks